# Populate datagridview (Rows) with an array of doubles

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm clueless on how to populate my datagridview with lap numbers as rows and lap times as columns. I would greatly appreciate any advice. Here is my code for the race laps and times array:

```
public double[] LapTimes_Method(int NumLaps, double LapTime)
{
   double[] raceLapArray = new double[NumLaps];
   for (int x = 0; x < NumLaps; x++)
   {
      Random Random_Numbers = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
      double RandomLapNumber;
      RandomLapNumber = Random_Numbers.Next(98, 102) / 100;
      double RandomTime;
      RandomTime = LapTime * RandomLapNumber;
      raceLapArray[x] = RandomTime;
   }
   return raceLapArray;
}
```

I apologize for the confusion. Here's the code where I attempted to populate the datagridview rows with different lap numbers:

```
private void dgd_Simulation_Results_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Simulation_Calculations Name2;
        Name2 = new Simulation_Calculations();

        int input;
        bool isInt = int.TryParse(text_S_NumLaps.Text, out input);

        double input2;
        bool isDouble = double.TryParse(text_S_Lap_Time.Text, out input2);

        double[] raceLapArray;

        if (isInt == true && isDouble == true)
        {

            raceLapArray = Name2.LapTimes_Method(input, input2);
            dgd_Simulation_Results.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[input].Value = "Lap" + input;

        }
        DataGridColumnStyle.Equals(input, input2);
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. I don't know how to populate my datagridview with the stored values. With Numlaps as rows and LapTimes as columns.

Comment: What does the code that populates your datagridview look like? What have you tried so far? Do you know how to populate this type of control? What type of data are you trying to display. **What is the question you are asking?**

Comment: I've tried to populate the dgd like a listbox but that's obviously not going to work: 'dgd_Simulation_Results.NewRowIndex.Equals("Lap " + (x + 1));
                        dgd_Simulation_Results.Columns.Add(raceLapArray[x]);' . I'm trying to display strings "LapNumber" as rows and next to each corresponding "LapNumber" there is a "Laptime."

Comment: This is where you should start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView(v=vs.110).aspx There's a nice example of how to use the DataGridView class at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @FodderZone the [DataGridView.Rows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) article is also is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

To populate a datagridview, in general use:

```
for(your condition)
{
datagridviewName.Rows.Add(column1 value, column2 value, column3 value... etc);
}
```

In your case, the For loop condition statement would parse through your array.

For the column values, you would place in the index value that you wanted to output in the appropriate dgv column. (array[0], array[1], etc...)